# MuleSoft Anypoint RuntimeFabric Deployment Using Maven

Tags: maven, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-rtf

I see that deploying to Anypoint RuntimeFabric requires publishing the asset to Exchange. Is that mandatory ?

Few are mentioning its a mandatory and few say its not. Anyone tried deploying to Runtime Fabric directly using maven without publishing to exchange.

When i tried to deploy without publishing to exchange i got below error:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.5.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project rtf-cicd: Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.5.2:deploy failed: 400 Bad Request: {"message":"No application with the provided GAV could be retrieved from Exchange"} -> [Help 1]
```

Here are few articles/blogs from MuleSoft

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-deploy-a-Mule-4-application-to-Runtime-Fabric-with-Maven
https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/install-runtime-fabric-ci-cd-with-jenkins-and-nexus/
https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.9/deploy-maven-4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a prerequisite that the application is deployed to Exchange previously:

> The application is already published in Exchange

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/deploy-to-rtf#prerequisites